# How much fat can be removed after cooking medium ground beef into sauce?

Tags: fat, ground-beef

I bought medium ground beef when I intended to buy lean beef. I don't want to consume that amount of fat.

Suppose I fry the meat then add tomatoes (on the way to a [Bolognese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolognese_sauce) sauce), cool the result overnight in the fridge, and then discard the fat on top (which would be 100% saturated, I presume). Would I have discarded the majority of the fat?

**Update**

Relevant ideas can be found [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4167) and [there](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/37505).

Comment: Try frying it off as normal and then removing any unwanted fat by either straining or tipping (whilst hot/warm).

Comment: Is straining or tipping more effective than cooling overnight? Now that I think of it, perhaps straining followed by leaving on a paper towel is best. But then we'd worry about the chemicals in the paper towels. I asked: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/78303/41295

Comment: Hello Calaf, we prefer to have straight questions here. Your reasons to not want eating the fat, or self-castigation about buying what you did not want to buy, is distracting from the real question, and in this specific case, may even invite health debates (which are off topic). I removed that part, and left the question itself.

Comment: Also, don't forget to take a look at the "Related" panel on the right hand, the system there tries to find questions which might interest you and usually does a good job of it. In this case, the top related question is http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10283/how-do-you-properly-drain-the-grease-after-browning-ground-beef?rq=1, which is what you asked in the comment.

Comment: I can only comment as to what I would do in this case.  I would strain it and, if needed there after use kitchen towel to blot away anything else I didn't want - however, careful you don't 'blot' away juices etc that you do want.  If kitchen towels are a no no for you, how about using a clean (and I mean clean clean) t towel.  I know, a bit of serious washing of it afterwards, but what the heck!  Perhaps you could look for a kitchen towel that is sort of chemical free - hypoallergenic?  Your thoughts?

Comment: @rumtscho I see your point. But I would have loved to hear feedback about the kinds of lighting in a store that merchants could have used (unscrupulously, but legally) to confuse the fat content. Should I take my own flashlight, with an intact blue/green spectrum, to be certain? That's for sure an altogether different question.

Comment: We discourage asking two questions in one. You could try asking such a question about lighting separately, I don't know how the community will react. We have a rule to not ask "rants disguised as questions" and this can encroach that territory - it may work if you word it neutrally, though.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing with sauce is problematic as the fat will mix with the sauce.

Fry just the meat slowing and break it up very fine.  While hot strain it in a metal colander.  You can even pat dry with paper towels.

Then mix with cooked sauce.  It will not be as good but you saved the meat.

Even if you buy lean fat will drain.